# how to retrieve subtrees while parsing in nlp

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I would like to retrieve the sub tress while parsing the sentence like below:

```
sentence = "All new medications must undergo testing before they can be 
             prescribed"
parser = stanford.StanfordParser()
tree_parse = parser.raw_parse(sentence)
for i, sub_tree in enumerate(tree_parse[0].subtrees()):
   if sub_tree.label() in ["S"]:
      sub_list = sub_tree
      print(sub_list)
```

What I am expecting is to access the subtree labeled "S" individually like below:

## first subtree

```
(S
  (NP (DT All) (JJ new) (NNS medications))
  (VP
    (MD must)
    (VP
      (VB undergo)
```

## second subtree

```
(S
    (VP
      (VBG testing)
      (SBAR
        (IN before)
```

## 3rd subtree

```
(S
          (NP (PRP they))
          (VP (MD can) (VP (VB be) (VP (VBN prescribed)))))))))))
```

But the actual output is like below:

```
 (NP (DT All) (JJ new) (NNS medications))
  (VP
  (MD must)
  (VP
    (VB undergo)
    (S
      (VP
        (VBG testing)
        (SBAR
          (IN before)
          (S
            (NP (PRP they))
            (VP (MD can) (VP (VB be) (VP (VBN prescribed))))))))))
 How to access the sub tress individually like accessing items in a list?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already getting the subtrees: A subtree contains everything below its root, so the output you show is correctly retrieved as the "subtree" below the top-level `S`. Your will then output the subtree dominating "testing before they can be prescribed", and finally the lower-most `S`, dominating "they can be prescribed".

Incidentally, you can get the `S` subtrees directly by specifying a [filter](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.subtrees):

```
for sub_tree in tree_parse[0].subtrees(lambda t: t.label() == "S"):
    print(sub_tree)
```